# Is this an appropriate function definition?

Tags: c, struct

My professor provides the function definition in our homework so that we do the assignment the way she wants. The definition she provided looks like this;

```
void outputStudents(struct student [], int size)
```

Usually she provides the names of the variables, for grading purposes, so I wanted to be sure. Do I need to change the declaration to include a name for the student object, such as

```
void outputStudents(struct student classroom[], int size)
```

or is there a way to access it the way it's written?

Sorry if this seems like an obvious question, but structs and pointers are throwing me for a loop (no pun intended), so I want to make sure before I change anything. She does make mistakes sometimes, so its hard to tell if I'm just confused, or if there's an error in the problem.

Edit: Ok, thanks guys. I understand that variables can have any name, but like I mentioned, usually she provides us with the exact function header should say(and takes off points if we change it unnessesarily), for grading purposes since she and the other two TAs look at hundreds of these a week. So I wanted to be sure that I wasn't overlooking something.

Comment: Just to clarify.  In your question, you are referring to two separate things, first:  _professor provides the function_ ***definition*** _in our homework_, then second you ask: _Do I need to change the_ ***declaration*** _to include_.  Keep in mind, the ***declaration*** and ***definition*** are not (always) the same thing, and in the context of this question, that may lead to a little confusion in how people try to answer.   So, be careful to interpret the answers (all look fine) offered with the wording of your question in mind.  :)

Comment: In a nutshell, _prototypes_ (AKA _declarations_) do not require variable names.  For function _definitions_ (AKA _implementations_) all argument types except `void` require names.

Comment: @ryyker: Prototypes are not "AKA declarations". Function declaration is a wider concept than function prototype. All prototypes are declarations but not all declarations are prototypes.

Comment: @ryyker Sorry, my question is kind of pedestrian, and I kept looking up vocabulary as it came to me in order to be specific with my question. So you have the prototype before main, and then what you call the implementation, which I was trying to call the definition. Usually, the prof gives us the implementation, what to call the vars, etc, not because we can't come up with it on our own, but because she has hundreds of these to grade. So my kind of pedestrian question is, 'this is not a full implementation, correct?' because I wanted to be sure before I changed it at all.

Comment: @AndryT - Yes, agreed.  Also modified my answer below with the clarification that _if prototype does not exist, then a function's definition serves also as it's declaration_.  Thank you, good point.

Comment: @Jack, _this is not a full implementation, correct?'_  That is correct.  If that first code example is supposed to represent an implementation, it is missing (and needs) the variable name for the `struct`. And the `{...}` (all the other stuff).    `int size` is of course okay.  ***Read also AndreyT's*** comments to me.  He made some good clarifying points about some mis-statements regarding _declaration_ I made (oops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument name will be important only when implementing. 
In declaration they can be ignored because there the type is most important thing.
You have to assign a name to the argument to be able to use it of course.

Answer (score 5):

Names of arguments can be omitted from the declaration (only the types matter). When you actually implement it, you must of course name the argument in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

***A prototype:*** (referred to as *declaration* in other answers)

```
void outputStudents(struct student [], int ); //note the ; at end of statement
```

requires no function arguments to be included.  However, (and of course)

***The function implementation***,  (sometimes also referred to as *definition*, and sometimes *declaration* (if no previous prototype))

```
void outputStudents(struct student classroom[], int size)   
{   
    //do stuff here...
}
```

always requires argument names for every type. (except void)

***Note:***  *Prototypes* are not *required* in C, only that the function be ***declared*** before it is referenced (or called) by any other function.  ***Note also:*** If there is no previous *prototype*, then the function *definition* will also serve as its *declaration*.
***An exception*** regarding whether a prototype is *required:* If compiler options are set to flag *non-prototyped functions*.   In that case, a warning would be issued at compile time.  (if your teacher/professor *explicitly requires* a prototype, then of course they are also required :)

Comment: Prototypes are not required in C, only that the function be *declared* before it is referenced (or called) by any other function. *Declared*, not *defined*.

Comment: @AndreyT - Changed my answer.  Good call.  The semantics got me.  See my additional note.  Thank you

Comment: This is the most complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must give a name of the struct variable. The second thing, just for sake of your knowledge, you have to give the name of the variable in formal arguments only if you are writing.

```
void outputStudents(struct student classroom[], int size)
```

or

```
void outputStudents(struct student *classroom, int size)
```

are the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote.

Comment: user2673577 - Not the down voter, but the actual question is: _Do I need to change the_ ***declaration*** _to include a name_...  So, strictly speaking, you are not correct in saying _you must give a name of the struct variable_.  ***However***, there is some ambiguity in the way the question was asked (OP originally referred to the ***function definition***), which on the first reading lead me to the same conclusion.  Perhaps, if you fix the wording in your answer, the down voter(s) may retract.  (It would be the right thing to do)

Comment: And your formatting, with caps and punctuation. To quote Roland, "I don't understand what you wrote."